# When I update my context.provider's value, the child components don't change color

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-context, darkmode

I have some trouble implementing multiple color themes into my website. I have made a button connected to a state toggle, and every time the state switches, a useEffect handler sets the value of my context.provider to dark/light theme. When I log the useEffect handler it changes the theme, however the child components are not affected by it.

This is my App.tsx:

```
import {
  useContext,
  useState,
  Provider,
  createContext,
  useEffect,
} from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.scss";
import Nav from "./components/ui/nav/Nav";
import Welcome from "./components/ui/welcome/Welcome";
import Section from "./components/ux/section/Section";
import Prices from "./components/ui/prices/Prices";
import { themes, ThemeContext } from "./components/theme/theme";
import Background from "./components/ui/background/Background";

function App() {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const [darkmode, setdarkmode] = useState(true);
  const themeMode = themes.light;
  useEffect(() => {
    const themeMode = darkmode ? themes.light : themes.dark;
    console.log(themeMode);
  }, [darkmode]);

  document.body.style.background = theme.primary;
  document.body.style.color = theme.text;
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={themeMode}>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setdarkmode(!darkmode);
        }}
      >
        hello
      </button>
      <Background />

      <Section content={<Welcome />} />
      <Section content={<Prices />} />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is one of my components that should use the updated theme:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import "./button.scss";
import { themes, ThemeContext } from "../../theme/theme";
export default function Button(props: {
  invert: boolean;
  link: string | URL;
  content: string;
}) {
  var style = {};

  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const buttonStyle = {
    color: theme.primary,
    background: theme.cta,
    border: "solid 2px " + theme.cta,
  };
  const invertStyle = {
    color: theme.cta,
    background: theme.primary,
    border: "solid 2px " + theme.cta,
  };

  props.invert ? (style = invertStyle) : (style = buttonStyle);
  const [colorStyle, setColorStyle] = useState(false);
  colorStyle
    ? props.invert
      ? (style = buttonStyle)
      : (style = invertStyle)
    : props.invert
    ? (style = invertStyle)
    : (style = buttonStyle);
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        window.location.assign(props.link);
      }}
      onMouseEnter={() => {
        setColorStyle(!colorStyle);
      }}
      onMouseLeave={() => {
        setColorStyle(!colorStyle);
      }}
      className="ux-btn"
      style={style}
    >
      {props.content}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `const themeMode = themes.light;` in your component. This does exactly what it says: sets the `themeMode` variable to be the constant `themes.light`.

When you attempt (I presume) to "change it" in the event handler, you're doing `const themeMode = darkmode ? themes.light : themes.dark;`, but with nothing else in that function (other than a `console.log`) - as this variable is only scoped to that one function, it does not change the same-named variable outside.

Even if you made it change the outer variable (by declaring the outer variable with `let` instead of `const` and not shadowing the variable inside the function but updating its value), that won't work at all well with React.

The solution is to use state instead:

- replace `const themeMode = themes.light` with `const [themeMode, setThemeMode] = useState(themes.light);`
- inside the event handler, replace `const themeMode = darkmode ? themes.light : themes.dark;` with `setThemeMode(darkmode ? themes.light : themes.dark);`

Making the above 2 changes will work - but you can still simplify your component quite a lot. You don't need both `darkMode` and `themeMode` in state, as one is simply calculated from the other. If you just use one state variable you also won't need a `useEffect` to automatically update one based on the other. But I'll leave you to sort out those problems - I hope this helps you get started, at least!

Comment: you're a legend! I changed it to a state variable and put the logic insite the onClick handler and removed the useEffect hook and it works like a charm! Will accept your answer as the official answer in 2 minutes :). By the way, unbelievable speed in answering this question.